# Proof of Weak Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> For a sequence of i.i.d. random variable $(X_n)$ with $\Bbb{E}X=m$,  $\overline{X}_n=(X_1+...+X_n)/n$, then $\overline{X}_n\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow}m$.

Since $(X_n)$ are i.i.d., $(X_n)$ induce the same probability measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb{R}$. So
$$\Bbb{P}\{|\overline{X}_n-m|>\epsilon\}=\int_{\{|\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}-m|>\epsilon\}}\Bbb{1}(\mathrm{d}\mu)^n$$
where $(\mathrm{d}\mu)^n$ is the product measure of $\mu$. I want to know if we can prove weak law of large numbers by this representation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use the Chebyshev inequality.  First, you might want to compute $Var\left(\overline{X}_n\right)$.  This would of course assume $X_1$ has finite variance.

Comment: @Michael Yes, sir! I know the standard proof, first consider the case of finite variation and use Chebyshev inequality, then using truncation to approximate the general case. But I want to know if my attempt is useful.

Comment: I don't see how your integral helps to identify concentration properties. The key idea in all proofs of the law of large numbers is to compute the variance of either $\overline{X}_n$ or its truncated version. Somewhere you will want to use the fact that $E[(X_i-m)(X_j-m)]=0$ (or its truncated version $E[(\tilde{X}_i-m_i)(\tilde{X}_j-m_j)]=0$).